# Extra spaces in gridview inside recyclerview

Tags: android, gridview

Hallo i have some problem in gridviiew inside recyclerview, there is some spaces above grid item 2. like this pic. that spaces changes dinamicaly if i reload content inside recyclerview.

normal recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  />
```

item cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_margin="2dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"


    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

[image]

Comment: where is xml ????

Comment: xml added @IntelliJAmiya Amiya

Answer (score 0):

found weird solution by add 2 dummy content and remove it (item 1 and 2) in **recycler adapter onBindViewHolder** solved my problem.

```
if (position == 1 || position == 0) {
//              holder;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        0,
                        0
                );
                int margin = dpToPx(0);
                params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
                holder.cardview2.setLayoutParams(params);
                holder.cardview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            } else {
```

so whats is the problem?